# Production Crash on ios 15: CA::Display::DisplayLink::timer_status_callback

Tags: ios, swift, crash, quartz-core

[image]

Can someone help me about this crash. It's a production crash. I cannot replicate the issue nor understand the root cause . I searched related issue here ([Crash on ios 15: CA::Display::DisplayLink::timer_status_callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830474/crash-on-ios-15-cadisplaydisplaylinktimer-status-callback)) but haven't give any clue on the issue for me.

I tried to use Xcode Organizer to point me on the crash line but didn't help me. Asked one client where in the page happened this crash but I couldn't replicate it on my own device.